# Create balanced graph of n nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I need to create a graph that has shortest possible routes between all nodes with each node having at most 3 edges. According to wiki on signed graphs (that would be likely candidate for this task) it seems this is actually a NP-hard problem so no generic algorithm for `n` nodes actually exist. Is this correct or can this be solved perhaps with modified binary-search-trees? I was thinking connecting the leafs together in some pattern (and to the root).

Comment: Dijkstra with non-negative weights is O(n^2)? Could you tell more of your constraints (negative weights, undirected)?

Comment: The graph is undirected and will be modified (added to and removed from) and if that happens the changes should be ideally minimal to existing links but not necessarily.